# Why R^2 return negative and how to interpret them

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I am trying to apply different transformations to test my linear regression model this dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Year':  [1830, 1905, 1930, 1947, 1952, 1969],
        'Speed mph': [30,130,400,760,1500,25000],
        'Means of attaining speed': ['Railroad', 'Rairoad'
                                     , 'Airplane', 'Airplane', 'Airplane','Spaceship']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Year','Speed mph','Means of attaining speed'])
x = df['Year'].values
y = df['Speed mph'].values

df['U2'] = np.power(2,df['Speed mph'])

u = df['U2'].values

#regression part
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,u)
line = slope*x+intercept
plt.plot(x, line, 'r', label='r_value={:.2f} p_value {:.2f}'.format(r_value,p_value))
#end

plt.scatter(x,u, color="k")
plt.title('${Y^2}$ vs X',fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Year,X',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('${Y^2}$',fontsize=14)

plt.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=14)

plt.legend(fontsize=9)

plt.show()
```

This returns R square value of -0.90 and p value = 0.01. P value is significant but why negative -0.90? Hope someone can please educate me.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code:

```
df['U2'] = np.power(2,df['Speed mph'])
```

The np.power function was applied not as you expect, it set the first row to 1073741824 and the rest of rows are zeros.

```
print[df]

   Year  Speed mph Means of attaining speed          U2
0  1830         30                 Railroad  1073741824
1  1905        130                  Rairoad           0
2  1930        400                 Airplane           0
3  1947        760                 Airplane           0
4  1952       1500                 Airplane           0
5  1969      25000                Spaceship           0
```

Modify that line to:

```
df['U2'] = df['Speed mph'].apply(lambda x: x * x)
```

or

```
df['U2'] = df['Speed mph'].apply(np.square)
```

so df becomes:

```
   Year  Speed mph Means of attaining speed         U2
0  1830         30                 Railroad        900
1  1905        130                  Rairoad      16900
2  1930        400                 Airplane     160000
3  1947        760                 Airplane     577600
4  1952       1500                 Airplane    2250000
5  1969      25000                Spaceship  625000000
```

finally

```
r_value=0.46 p_value=0.36
```

Now, every thing is nice :)

Answer (score 1):

[`linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) returns the linear correlation coefficient *R*, not *R*<sup>2</sup>. The latter, being a square of a real number, *can’t* be negative.

For *R* = −0.9, we have *R*<sup>2</sup> = 0.81.

A negative correlation coefficient means that [the relationship between the variables is negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_relationship) (also known as “anticorrelated”, which is *not* the same as uncorrelated!). That is, the slope of the linear regression is negative (goes down from left to right over the x-axis).